# Como altero uma linha da data table ao seleciona-la?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Neste código consigo seleciona-la e no console.log ter acesso as informações, porém não sei como poderia alterar a mesma:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#tableproduct').DataTable();

    $('#tableproduct tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var pos = oTable.row(this).index();
        var row = oTable.row(pos).data();
        console.log(row);
    })
});
```

Preciso que ao selecionar a linha seja alterado a propriedade readOnly de true para false do input.

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: Preciso que ao selecionar a linha seja alterado a propriedade readOnly de true para false do input.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque esta informação, e se possível a estrutura html que vc está usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei a estrutura da sua tabela, mas deve ser algo assim que você procura:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#tableproduct');

    $('#tableproduct tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        
        let inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (let input of inputs) {
          input.readOnly = false;
        } 
       
        console.log(this);
        
    })
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableproduct" class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Código</th>
            <th>Cor</th>
            <th>Tamanho</th>
   <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th style="width:25%">% do estoque total</th>
   <th>Ação</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>Azul</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><span style="cursor: pointer;" class="label label-success">Lançam .manual</span></td>
  </tr>
          
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: erro meu, já foi corrigido :D

Comment: blz, meu +1 pela rápida correção

Comment: Leo, obrigado meu amigo, o código funcionou perfeitamente